# Differentiate $\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}/(1+f(x))$

Tags: derivatives

Is there a trick I'm overseeing?

I have $\frac{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}{1+f(x)} = \sqrt{1+f(x)^2} \cdot (1+y)^{-1}$ .

First differentiation:

$$[\sqrt{1+f(x)^2} \cdot (1+y)^{-1}]' = \frac{2f'(x)}{2(1+f(x)\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}} - \frac{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}{(f(x)+1)^2}\ .$$

The further differentiations are then getting more and more complex - maybe this is correct, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your second term should also have $f'(x)$

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of problems, where you have products and ratios, I think that logarithmic differentiation is quite useful.

Let

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}{1+f(x)}$$ so $$\log(y)=\frac 12 \log\big(1+f(x)^2\big)- \log\big(1+f(x)\big)$$ Now, differentiate $$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{f(x) f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}-\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)}=\frac{(f(x)-1) f'(x)}{(1+f(x)) \left(1+f(x)^2\right)}$$ Replacing $y$, we then have $$y'=\frac{(f(x)-1) f'(x)}{(1+f(x))^2 \sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}$$

By the way, tou could further continue starting from $$y'=\frac{(f(x)-1) f'(x)}{(1+f(x)) \left(1+f(x)^2\right)}y$$ express $\log(y')$ as a sum of logarithms and differentiate all the pieces ($y''$ will then be expressed as a function of $y$ and $y'$).

Comment: It should be noted that $\log(y)$ is defined only when $y>0$, so this is only a formal way.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But I almays found it was very convenient for complex stuff. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}{1+f(x)}$. By $(\frac{u}{v})'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$ and the chain rule, we have:$$g'(x)=\frac{\frac{f(x)f'(x)}{\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}(1+f(x))-\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}f'(x)}{(1+f(x))^2}=\frac{f(x)f'(x)-f'(x)}{(1+f(x))^2\sqrt{1+f(x)^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You missed a part.

Please check red color  below

HINT:
$$(\frac{U}{V})'=\frac{U'}{V}-\frac{U. \color{red}{ V'}}{V^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Either use f(x) or y in the expression during differentiation to avoid such errors.